# A functional swap function except in one case

Tags: c

This swap function is fully functional except when the input is two arrays with the same values:

```
void permuter(int* a, int* b) {
    *a = *a + *b;
    *b = *a - *b;
    *a = *a - *b;
}

int main(void) {
    int i[0];
    int j[0];
    i[0] = 5;
    j[0] = 5;
    permuter(&j[0], &i[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

using `printf();` `i[0] = 0` and `j[0] = 0`.

Comment: Your two arrays have size 0, so your code is undefined behavior. The swap would work unless both pointers are the same. But there is no reason to swap this way.

Comment: @interjay Even with bigger arrays, the problem is still there. Will just swap using a temporary in the future as adviced by the answer.

Comment: You might also want to consider what happens if `permuter()` is passed two equal pointers - the result is probably not what you expect.     Also, if any of the additions or subtractions overflow, the behaviour is undefined.    The conventional way, using a temporary,. exhibits neither problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between two different swapping function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58462258/what-is-the-difference-between-two-different-swapping-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common problem with clever swaps (see also: XOR swap). Do it the straightforward way, with a temporary!

```
int t = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = t;
```

In practice, you could probably check that the pointers are different to avoid *this* problem, but `*a + *b` still has undefined behaviour on overflow and there’s just no reason to have to worry about that.