# How XOR Assignment operator ^= is utilized to reverse an array in c

Tags: c++, c

i encountered to this function

```
void reverseArray(int *a,int n)
{
for(int i=0,j=n-1;i<j;i++,j--)
{
a[i]^=a[j]^=a[i]^=a[j];
}
}
```

which is reversing a given array but I can't wrap my mind around how does this reverse an array, isn't Xor operator only returns the non-common bits.
so what's the logic behind this to reverse the given array.

Comment: Re “the non-common bits”: When you flip the non-common bits in `a[j]`, it makes those bits have the values they have in `a[i]`, so the result equals `a[i]`. Then, from right-to-left, `a[i]^=a[j]` finds the non-common bits (`^`) and stores them (`^=`) in `a[i]`. Then `a[j]^=a[i]^a[j]` flips those bits in `a[j]`, making it equal to the original `a[i]`. Then `a[i]^=a[j]^=a[i]^=a[j]` XORs the non-common bits that were stored in `a[i]` with the original value of `a[i]` (now in `a[j]`), so that flips the non-common bits to make the original `a[j]`, which is stored in `a[i]`.

Comment: It should be noted, however, the behavior of this statement is not defined by the C standard, because the updates to `a[i]` are not sequenced.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That is correct, I will add that to my answer below.

Comment: Be aware that there are two diametrically opposite ways to answer this question. (1) There was a (perverse) goal that the author of this code was trying to achieve, and we can explain what that goal was, and how it was achieved.  But (2) as you yourself have seen firsthand, this code is impossible to understand on first reading.  Moreover, it's undefined: it's not even guaranteed to work.  So, while this may be a useful example to learn from, it is absolutely *not* something to be admired, emulated, or used in a real, practical program, ever!

Comment: See [Question 20.15c](http://c-faq.com/misc/swapnotemp.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: See [What is the difference between two different swapping function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58462258)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the expression `a^=b^=a^=b` is to exchange the values of `a` and `b`. It becomes more clear if we split it up (where `a_0` and `b_0` are the original values of `a` and `b`):

1. First assignment, `a^=b` makes `a_1=(a_0^b_0)`.
2. Second assignment, `b^=a` makes `b_1=(b_0^a_1)=(b_0^(a_0^b_0))=a_0`
3. Third assignment, `a^=b` makes `a_2=(a_1^b_1)=((a_0^b_0)^a_0)=b_0`

Thus we end up with `a` having the original value of `b` and vice versa.

While the expression `a^=b^=a^=b` may work it is actually undefined behavior because the C standard does not specify the order of assignments. Instead, it must be sequenced explicitly: `a^=b; b^=a; a^=b;`.

Answer (score 3):

`a ^= b ^= a ^= b;` is a fancy way to swap two numbers, known as [XOR swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

You should prefer a much more readable `std::swap`, or (in C) a temporary variable.

Comment: s/fancy/obfuscated/.

Comment: C++ has `std::reverse`. You don't even need `std::swap` in a for-loop.