# Is there a case where bitwise swapping won't work?

Tags: c, bitwise-xor

At school someday several years ago I had to do a swap function that swaps two integers, I wanted to do this using bitwise operations without using a third variable, so I came up with this:

```
void swap( int * a, int * b ) {
    *a = *a ^ *b;
    *b = *a ^ *b;
    *a = *a ^ *b;
}
```

I thought it was good but when my function was tested by the school's correction program it found an error (of course when I asked they didn't want to tell me), and still today I don't know what didn't work, so I wonder in which case this method wouldn't work.

Comment: XOR swapping is just being so clever you outsmarted yourself.  Count the loads, stores, and xor operations, and compare that to "load `a` into `r1`, load `b` into `r2`, store `r2` into `a`, store `r1` into `b`".

Comment: It will fail if someone calls `int x = 5; swap(&x, &x);`.

Comment: @SteveSummit And undefined behavior results if any of the signed `int` values is an overflow.

Comment: @SteveSummit Oh yeah, it's true in the first statement `*a = *a ^ *b` it just sets `*a` (and `*b`) to 0

Comment: @AndrewHenle What do you mean by overflow ? How could it overflow since we're just modifying the bits ?

Comment: Andrew might have been thinking of the [alternative swap formulation involving subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58462258) instead of XOR.

Comment: @Fayeure [Some operators (the unary operator ~, and the binary operators <<, >>, &, ^, and |, collectively described as bitwise operators) are required to have operands that have integer type. These operators yield values that depend on the internal representations of integers, **and have implementation-defined and undefined aspects for signed types**.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p4)  For example, something like `~INT_MAX` might very well be a trap representation.  You out-clevered yourself when you decided to be obscure with code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wanted to do this using bitwise operations without using a third variable

Do you mind if I ask why?  Was there a practical reason for this limitation, or was it just an intellectual puzzle?

> when my function was tested by the school's correction program it found an error

I can't be sure what the correction program was complaining about, but one class of inputs this sort of solution is known to fail on is exemplified by

```
int x = 5;
swap(&x, &x);
printf("%d\n", x);
```

This prints `0`, not `5`.

You might say, "Why would anyone swap something with itself?"
They probably wouldn't, as I've shown it, but perhaps you can imagine that, in a mediocrely-written sort algorithm, it might end up doing the equivalent of

```
if(a[i] < a[j]) {
    /* they are in order */
} else {
    swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
}
```

Now, if it ever happens that `i` and `j` are the same, the `swap` function will wrongly zero out `a[i]`.

See also [What is the difference between two different swapping function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58462258)

Comment: No there wasn't any particular reason, it was just for my personnal knowlege and because I saw this method in a book and I liked it.

So if I just add `if (a == b) return ;` at the beginning it should work then ?

Comment: @Fayeure As far as I know that would have worked.

Comment: If `a[i] > a[j]`, surely `i != j` (for integers anyway).

Comment: @Nelfeal Ah, yes.  I guess I really meant `>=`.  Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Well, now if `a[i] == a[j]`, there is no point in swapping the values. I guess the code must be poorly written to end up in such a situation.

Comment: @Nelfeal Exactly.  Thus, "mediocrely-written".  (But: my goal was to present *a* scenario under which the posted `swap()` function could fail, not a *good* one! :-) )